# Objective-c Cocos2d moving a sprite

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I hope someone knows how to do the following with cocos2d:

I want a sprite to move but not in a single line by using

```
[cocosGuy runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]];
```

What I want is the sprite to do some kind of movements that I preestablish. For example in some point i want the sprirte to move for instance up and then down but in a curve. Do I have to do this with flash like this documents says?

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:animation

Does animation in this page means moving sprites or what?

Comment: Just a reminder: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CCBezierTo](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_bezier_to.html) / [CCBezierBy](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_bezier_by.html) actions for that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use Flash to create a sprite movement in a curve.

Here is one way of doing it.

Use the `scheduleUpdate` and in your `update` method, which typically runs 60 times per second, change the sprite's `position` property based on the `x,y` points in a curve of your choosing. You could define these points and store them in an array, or have them calculated as part of the `update` method, whatever works for you, and depending on your game's logic.

When the game automatically follows the `update` method, the sprite will change position and flow along the curve you specify based on the algorithm you choose to define those changing `x,y` points.